# How to see correct metrics for changes between two commits?

Tags: git

How properly use git diff   to count: added, modified, deleted and total lines of file for each file? Also, I need ignore blank and comments lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by:

```
git diff --stat <commit1> <commit2>
```

And for a quick history overview:

```
git log --stat
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't count total file lines in this case. And I need to ignore blank and comments line.